# How to make the Google Drive API authorization persist when refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I am using this javascript quickstart for the Google Drive API v3 (which i got [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js)) 
(i correctly filed my client id and my api key)

```
<p>Drive API Quickstart</p>

<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

<pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
  /* exported gapiLoaded */
  /* exported gisLoaded */
  /* exported handleAuthClick */
  /* exported handleSignoutClick */

  // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
  const CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
  const API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';

  // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
  const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest';

  // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
  // included, separated by spaces.
  const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly';

  let tokenClient;
  let gapiInited = false;
  let gisInited = false;

  document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

  /**
   * Callback after api.js is loaded.
   */
  function gapiLoaded() {
    gapi.load('client', intializeGapiClient);
  }

  /**
   * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
   * discovery doc to initialize the API.
   */
  async function intializeGapiClient() {
    await gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
    });
    gapiInited = true;
    maybeEnableButtons();
  }

  /**
   * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
   */
  function gisLoaded() {
    tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES,
      callback: '', // defined later
    });
    gisInited = true;
    maybeEnableButtons();
  }

  /**
   * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
   */
  function maybeEnableButtons() {
    if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
      document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }

  /**
   *  Sign in the user upon button click.
   */
  function handleAuthClick() {
    tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
      if (resp.error !== undefined) {
        throw (resp);
      }
      document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
      await listFiles();
    };

    if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
      // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
      // when establishing a new session.
      tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
    } else {
      // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
      tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
    }
  }

  /**
   *  Sign out the user upon button click.
   */
  function handleSignoutClick() {
    const token = gapi.client.getToken();
    if (token !== null) {
      google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
      gapi.client.setToken('');
      document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
      document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
      document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  }

  /**
   * Print metadata for first 10 files.
   */
  async function listFiles() {
    let response;
    try {
      response = await gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        'pageSize': 10,
        'fields': 'files(id, name)',
      });
    } catch (err) {
      document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
      return;
    }
    const files = response.result.files;
    if (!files || files.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No files found.';
      return;
    }
    // Flatten to string to display
    const output = files.reduce(
        (str, file) => `${str}${file.name} (${file.id}\n`,
        'Files:\n');
    document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
```

So when i click on Authorize it will display a pop-up authorize Google to access my drive, and it will display the metadata of the first 10 files.
The problem is that every time i refresh the page, i need to authorize Google to access my drive.
Is there anyway to make that persistent ? 
I'm planning to add a button to call listFiles(), instead of executing it when handleAuthClick() is treated. (sorry if my english is bad)

Comment: It should be saving the auth in a cookie but the issue is this is client side JavaScript there is no way to really store the access unless you are using a server sided language.

Comment: I took a javascript quickstart from drive api but i used it in a symfony project that is working in PHP. I basically pasted the code on a .html.twig file. Is there any way to make this work using PHP ?